# Find the id of the last window of a process launched bash linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm on Ubuntu and I want to find the Id of the last window of firefox.

I write a script which open a new firefox window, close it and open it again (every 30mn).
I take a picture of the window with imagemagick and I use the ID of the window.

I can do all of that but I've a problem with the ID.

I find it with this :

```
firefox -new-window http://www.flightradar24.com/45.75,5.06/10;
sleep 5;
ID_W=`xwininfo -name "Flightradar24.com - Live flight tracker! - Mozilla Firefox" | awk '/Window id:/ {print $4}'`;
```

It works for the first time but after, the ID is always the same. How I can get the last id of the window launched ? The current window, not the id of the first window, this window is now close.
I can get the id of the process firefox of course.

Someone can help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you take that screenshot? There are better ways to achieve this.

Comment: Ok, why not ? I'm listening...  It's true my technique is brutal but I could not see how else to do.

Comment: Was searching for the link. The tool is called [wkhtml2pdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). Basically it wraps a headless webkit browser (having js enabled) and takes the screenshot for you. I tried it with your page and it works properly..

Comment: Oh thank's I will check that. So you download the html code and after you create the image ? And this works ? Because on the page Flightradar, the page moves with Javascript no ? Do you have an example ?

Comment: I uploaded my first result on http://metashock.de/test.pdf ... I have not tweaked window size, ... Just wanted to check if it is basically working with that page's javascript.. I simply executed `wkhtml2pdf http://www.flightradar24.com/45.75,5.06/10 test.pdf`

Comment: Btw, your idea isn't that bad, wkhtml2pdf follows a similar idea. But they are starting the browser without a GUI, in a so called *headless* mode. Also there are competing solutions using headless mode. You may search for this. I expect them being able to export an image directly, rather than just pdf..

Comment: An alternate track  to pursue.... Run firefox in the background using `&` at the end of the line. Then the PID is stored in shell variable `$!`.

Comment: Tested! Thank you very much, it is much easier!
Thank's for your trick shelter ;)

Comment: How did you manage to get the planes on the map? When I attempt to do the same thing, the plane overlays don't show.
I'm using URL http://www.flightradar24.com/41.98,-87.91/8 which is just filled.

Solved it with the Javacscript delay option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works. There is surely better!

I use the var cpt because Gnome can't change the background if the name is the same...

```
cpt='0';

while [ 1 ]; 
do
    wkhtmltoimage -q http://www.flightradar24.com/45.94,4.8/8 "image$cpt.png"
    convert "image$cpt.png" -crop 600x395+200+100 "image$cpt.png"
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/antoine/fond/image$cpt.png";   
    sleep 5;
    rm "image$cpt.png"
    cpt=$(($cpt +1))
done;
```

Thank you for your help!